# Do you have any idea on this scalar-by-matrix derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to find out the derivative

$$\frac { d({ x }^{ T }W{ W }^{ T }x) }{ dW }$$

where $x$ is $n \times 1$ and $W$ is $n \times m$, using

$$\frac { d({ x }^{ T }Wx) }{ dW } = {x}^{T} x$$

but I don't know how. Do you have any idea on how to compute this derivative?

Comment: Aren't you derivating with respect to $x$ rather than $W$ ? $d/dx$ instead of $d/dW$ would make more sense to my eyes...

Comment: @Evargalo I'm trying to derivate with respect to W! Check out "Scalar-by-Matrix Derivative" in wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix

Comment: The gradient of $x^{\top} W x$ with respect to $W$, 

$$ \frac{d\big( x^{\top}Wx \big)}{dW} $$

as you wrote, is $x x ^{\top}$. Not $Wx + W^{\top}x$.

Comment: @jibounet Oops, sorry. I was confused with derivative with respect to ${x}$ !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed, let $f$ be the real-valued function such that:

$$ \forall x \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}), \; f(x) = x^{\top}WW^{\top}x. $$

The gradient of $f$ with respect to $W$, denoted by $\nabla f(W)$ is the matrix in $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that:

$$ \forall H \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}), \; f(W+H) = f(W) + \left\langle \nabla f(W), H \right\rangle + o(\Vert H \Vert) $$

where $\left\langle \cdot, \cdot \right\rangle$ (resp. $\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ denotes the canonical inner product (resp. norm induced by the inner product)  on $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$. That is: $\left\langle M,N \right\rangle = \mathrm{tr}(M^{\top}N)$ for any $M,N \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Here:

$$
\begin{align*}
f(W+H) & = {} x^{\top}(W+H)(W+H)^{\top}x \\[2mm]
 & = x^{\top} \big( W W^{\top} + W H^{\top} + H W^{\top} + H H^{\top} \big) x \\[2mm]
 & = f(W) + x^{\top} W H^{\top} x + x^{\top} H W^{\top} x + o(\Vert H \Vert).
\end{align*}
$$

Note that:

$$
\begin{align*}
x^{\top} W H^{\top} x + x^{\top} H W^{\top} x & = \mathrm{tr}\big( x^{\top} W H^{\top} x + x^{\top} H W^{\top} x \big) \\[2mm]
 & = \mathrm{tr}\big( x x^{\top} W H^{\top} + x x^{\top} W H^{\top} \big) \\[2mm]
 & = \left\langle 2 x x^{\top} W, H \right\rangle.
\end{align*}
$$

By identification:

> $$ \nabla f(W) = 2 x x^{\top} W. $$

---

Let $\varphi$ be the map defined on $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ by:

$$ \forall M \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}), \; \varphi(M) = x^{\top} M x. $$

You can obtain the gradient of $f$ usign the chain rule. Define $\psi$ on $\mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$ by:

$$ \forall W \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R}), \; \psi(W) = W W^{\top}. $$

It follows that $f = \varphi \circ \psi.$
The chain rule gives:

$$ \mathrm{D}_{W}(\varphi \circ \psi) \cdot H = \mathrm{D}_{\psi(W)}\varphi \cdot \big( \mathrm{D}_{W}\psi \cdot H \big). $$

But because $\varphi$ is linear, $\mathrm{D}_{W}\varphi = \varphi$ for all $W$. Therefore:

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{D}_{W}(\varphi \circ \psi) \cdot H & = {} \varphi\big( \mathrm{D}_{W}\psi \cdot H \big) \\[2mm]
 & = x^{\top} \big( W H^{\top} + H W^{\top} \big) x.
\end{align*}
$$

Given that $\mathrm{D}_{W}(\varphi \circ \psi) \cdot H = \left\langle \nabla f(W), H \right\rangle$, we have again: $\nabla f(W) = 2 x x^{\top}W.$

Answer (score 0):

Using a colon to denote the trace product, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
you can jot down the function, differential, and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= x^TWW^Tx = x^TW:x^TW \cr
d\phi &= 2x^TW:x^TdW = 2xx^TW:dW \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= 2xx^TW \cr
}$$